# Cannot read stream (sslStream)

Tags: c#, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a SSL TCP server, it works on my browser and I can receive the hardcoded response. On the application, an exceptions is thown when the ReadLine function is used.

> Error: System.ArgumentException: Cannot read the stream    on
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean
>   detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
>   on System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)    on
>   App_Name.Program.Connection.Connect(String serverIp, Int32 serverPort,
>   ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)

```
tcpClient = new TcpClient(serverIp, serverPort);
sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(TrustAllCertificatesCallback));

streamReader = new StreamReader(sslStream);
streamWriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream);

string inputLine;

while ((inputLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ParseMessage(streamWriter, serverIp, inputLine);
}
```

Comment: Any type of firewall restriction or other access restriction that you can think of that would cause this in your environment?

Comment: Did you set the [`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) somewhere?

Comment: @rene No, that's the whole code except the certificate validation.

Comment: @igor It seems to work on the browser using my public IP.

Comment: Try setting it to one of the values from [SecurityProtocolType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why does it work on your browser? Is that an http server?

Comment: @rene hardcoded http response.

Comment: @rene ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072; Same error but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has to be added below the **Connect** function to initialize the handsake correctly.

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverIp);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Sender sorry, it's my question but I added the explanation, thanks.